# Why is Arel dropping the 'left outer join' when it builds SQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I'm trying to build the following query in Arel:

```
select a.* from (first nested query) as a
left outer join (second nested query) as b
on a.id = b.id
where b.id is null;
```

This is my best attempt:

```
query = a.
  project(a[Arel.star]).
  from(a_nested_sql).
  join(b_nested_sql, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).
  on(a[:id].eq(b[:id])).
  where(b[:id].eq(nil))
```

But it keeps dropping the 'left outer join' producing invalid SQL:

```
select a.* from (first nested query) as a
(second nested query) as b
on a.id = b.id
where b.id is null;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This was very helpful with a current problem, thanks for posting (question and solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting, this did the trick:

```
query = a_table.
  project(a_table[Arel.star]).
  from(a_nested_sql).
  join(
    b_table.join(b_nested_sql).join_sources,
    Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin
  ).
  on(a_table[:id].eq(b_table[:id])).
  where(b_table[:id].eq(nil))
```

Not really sure why as I don't really understand what join_sources does.